# Unable to take pictures using Camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I have written the following code, it compiles fine but the problem is it doesn't take any picture. I have added permissions and features in manifest file as directed by android documentation but still for some reason the app is not taking a picture. `I am not getting any errors in logcat either.` Here is the code.

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera cam;
Parameters param;
Bitmap imageTaken;

ImageView imView;

SurfaceView dummySurfaceView;

SurfaceHolder dummyHolder;

CamCallBack camCall ;

private static final String TAG = "CameraApp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

    imView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    dummySurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.dummySurface);


    dummyHolder= dummySurfaceView.getHolder(); 

    dummyHolder.addCallback(StartingPoint.this); 
    dummyHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

    param= cam.getParameters();

    cam.setParameters(param);

    cam.startPreview();

    cam.takePicture(null, null, camCall);

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try
    {           
        if(cam.getNumberOfCameras()==2)
        {       
            cam.open(0);

            cam.setPreviewDisplay(dummySurfaceView.getHolder());

            camCall = new CamCallBack();

            Log.d(TAG,"Try to open camera");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.d(TAG,"camera opening failed");

        Log.e(TAG,"recieved Exception",e);
    }


}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    cam.stopPreview();      
    cam.release(); 

    cam=null;
}


public class CamCallBack implements Camera.PictureCallback
{

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        imageTaken = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 
        imView.setImageBitmap(imageTaken);

        cam.release();


        Log.d(TAG,"Picture taken");
    }

}


 }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I am missing?

**EDIT:**

I know I can take pictures using `Camera activity` but that is not required in my app, so I didn't use it.

---

***UPDATE:***

Code updated. I have added a dummy Surfaceview in layout with 0dp height and width,but still the app is not working.

Can we take a picture from a service without letting the user know that picture has been taken?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try in an easy way, using Intent :

```
// at the beginning of your class
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 

//call cam request
public void takePic(){
    Intent cameraIntent = new       Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
}
//get photo taken
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                    ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourpic);
        Bitmap photoprise = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        photo.setImageBitmap(photoprise);
    }

}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I don't want to start the camera activity. Camera activity is not required in my app so I didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can take pictures using Camera activity but that is not required in my app, so I didn't use it.

Using the `Intent`-based solution would be a good idea under the circumstances.

> Is there anything I am missing?

- You have no preview pane
- You have not specified the picture size via the `Camera.Parameters`
- You have not specified the picture type (e.g., JPEG) via the `Camera.Parameters`

> What am I doing wrong?

Besides the above, you are opening the `Camera` twice, and ignoring the second one -- you might want to delete `cam.open(0)`.

Comment: ok. Even if I don't want to show the picture taken to the user, I have to use preview pane. and I want to take picture using front facing camera